# Inserting the Data using simple insert query in using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating the simple registration form using php.
I have done the validation check using php it works fine.. Select statement works fine to check whether the user name exits or not..
But here i have the problem in inserting the data.. Nothing happens while submitting . here is the full code.. all code is fine problem is with insert section.. please take a look on that..

```
<h3>* Required Fields<br/>  </h3>
         <?php 
         if(isset($_POST['username'])){ 
    # connect to the database here 
    # search the database to see if the user name has been taken or not 
    include 'config.php'; 
    $username=$_POST['username'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE userid='$username' "; 
    //$sql = mysql_query($query); 
    //$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $sql=mysql_query($query) or die($sql.">>".mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    //if($num>0){ //check if

    #check too see what fields have been left empty, and if the passwords match 
    if($row>0|| empty($_POST['fname'])||empty($_POST['lastname'])|| empty($_POST['username'])||empty($_POST['password1'])|| empty($_POST['password2'])|| empty($_POST['day'])|| empty($_POST['Month'])|| empty($_POST['year'])|| empty($_POST['gender']) || empty($_POST['contact'])||$_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2']|| $_POST['gender_select']='gender'|| $_POST['month_select']='month'|| $_POST['day_select']='day'|| $_POST['year_select']='year'){ 
        # if a field is empty, or the passwords don't match make a message 
        $error = '<h4>'; 

        if(empty($_POST['fname'])){ 
            $error .= 'First Name can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['lastname'])){ 
            $error .= 'Last Name can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])){ 
            $error .= 'Email can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['password1'])){ 
            $error .= 'Password can\'t be empty<br>'; 
        } 
        if(empty($_POST['password2'])){ 
            $error .= 'You must re-type your password<br>'; 
        } 

        if(empty($_POST['contact'])){ 
            $error .= 'contact is not selected<br>'; 
        } 
        if($_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password2']){ 
            $error .= 'Passwords don\'t match<br>'; 
        } 
        if($row>0){ 
            $error .= 'User Name already exists<br>'; 
        } 
        if($_POST['gender_select'] == 'gender'){
        $error.= "Please select a gender<br>";
        }
        if($_POST['month_select'] == 'month'){
        $error.= "Please select a month<br>";
        }
        if($_POST['day_select'] == 'day'){
        $error.= "Please select a day<br>";
        }
        if($_POST['year_select'] == 'year'){
        $error.= "Please select a year<br>";
        }

        $error .= '</h4>'; 
    }else{ 

                $ftname=$_POST['fname'];
                $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
                $gender=$_POST['gender'];
                $bday=$_POST['day_select'];
                $byear=$_POST['year_select'];
                $bmonth=$_POST['month_select'];
                $username=$_POST['username'];
                $password=$_POST['password1'];
                $contact=$_POST['contact'];
        $query= mysql_query(" insert into Account (firstname,lastname,gender,bday,byear,bmonth,userid,password,contactno) values 
                             ('$ftname','$lastname','$gender','$bday','$byear','$bmonth','$username','$password','$contact')") or die(mysql_error());

                if($query){

                    echo "New record was saved.";  
               // echo "<script>alert('Congratulation! You Create account successfully! ')</script>";
                          }
                else
                {
                     echo "Sorry no record saved.";
                }
    } 
} 
# echo out each variable that was set from above, 
# then destroy the variable. 
if(isset($error)){ 
    echo $error; 
    unset($error); 
} 
?> 

        </div>

            <form id="send" name="form" method="post" action="">

                <p>

                <label for="name">Name *</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname"  />
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="lastnamme">Father Name *</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname"  />
                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="username">Email Address *</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"  />
                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="password">Password *</label>
                <input type="password" name="password1"  />
                </p>
                 <p>

                <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password *</label>
                <input type="password" name="password2"   />
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="dob">Date of Birth *</label>
                <select name="day_select">
                 <option value="day" >Day&nbsp;</option>
                  <?php for($i=0;$i<=31;$i++)
                                {
                                 ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i."<br>"; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>

          &nbsp;
          <select name="month_select"  >
              <option value="month" >Month*</option>

              <option value="January">January</option>
              <option value="February">February</option>
              <option value="March">March</option>
              <option value="April">April</option>
              <option value="May">May</option>
              <option value="June">June</option>
              <option value="July">July</option>
              <option value="August">August</option>
              <option value="September">September</option>
              <option value="October">October</option>
              <option value="November">November</option>
              <option value="December">December</option>
              <option value="unknown" >Unknown</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
           <select name="year_select" >
           <option value="year" >Year&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
            <?php for($i=1920;$i<=2013;$i++)
                                {
                                 ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo  $i."<br>"; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>

                </p>

                <p>

                <label for="genderr">Gender *</label>

                <select name="gender_select"  >
                <option value="gender">Gender </option>
                <option value="male">Male </option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="other">other</option>
                </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label for="contactno">Contact No *</label>
                <input type="text" name="contact"  />
                </p>

                <p>


                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                </p>

            </form>




            </div>

        <!--END #signup-inner -->
        </div>

    <!--END #signup-form -->   
    </div>

            </div>

            </div><!-- end content -->

        </div><!-- end main -->

        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using MySQLi now instead of MySQL. And you also definitely need to check your inputs first to avoid SQL injection!

```
$ftname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
$lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$gender=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']);
$bday=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['day_select']);
$byear=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['year_select']);
$bmonth=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['month_select']);
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password1']);
$contact=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact']);

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Account
(firstname,lastname,gender,bday,byear,bmonth,userid,password,contactno) 
VALUES ('".$ftname."','".$lastname."','".$gender."','".$bday."','".$byear."','".$bmonth."','".$username."','".$password."','".$contact."')") 
or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

However you'll need to define $con at the start of the script. It's the connection to the MySQL database -

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating your values correctly in your insert statement.
should be

mysql_query(" insert into Account (firstname,lastname,gender,bday,byear,bmonth,userid,password,contactno) values 
                             ('".$ftname."','".$lastname."','".$gender."','".$bday."','".$byear."','".$bmonth."','".$username."','".$password."','".$contact."')") or die(mysql_error());

However be carefull your approach is prone to sql injection. You shouldn't be concatenating values originating from public forms directly to sql queries. You need to either escape the values carefully or use prepared statements with PDO.